Understanding folder & file permissions
I would like to have a folder with file and subfolders which cannot be deleted or renamed by users or even the owner/admin (with admin privileges I'd ideally like the admin to have the ability to delete/rename with some kind of confirmation or password but for sake of argument lets try to implement the restrictions on everyone).
I have tried going through Properties>Security>Advanced and disabling inheritance and then editing the advanced permissions for Everyone as well as for the Owner (which I thought was part of Everyone) and Denying: Delete, Write attributes, and Write extended attributes; I have also denied Full Control, which automatically unchecks when I deny the others. I actually applied these same conditions to the files and to the folder in which they are contained.
By doing this I hoped to that I would be unable to delete the files/folder and to rename them, while still being able to open them, read them, modify them (like add text and save for a .txt for example).
However, the result was that I can still delete and rename these files and folders just them same. There aren't even any warnings or pop us. The only thing is there is a little blue and yellow shield symbol next to delete and rename in the right-click menu but I can still delete and rename just the same if I click them.
The only way I can actually prevent them from being deleted or renamed is if I deny all other permissions. In that case I get pop-ups saying I don't have permission to do those actions and I have to see the owner to obtain permission . However, I am not even able to open the file in that case (all actions are restricted on the files which is far more restriction than I wanted.)
Is there some conflict I am not understanding here? Is it not possible to restrict these specific permissions? I am not sure I understand what exactly they mean and how they work.

What you want is impossible on Windows. An Administrator on Windows has the ability to take ownership of any folder.

Can the administrator set these permissions for others? Even for himself?

As an Administrator I can take ownership of any file on the system. Only a matter of how difficult that operation is and what will break if I do, this is a matter of having a written policy, and making sure users don’t use elevated permissions to access files their user role isn’t allowed to have.

I still don't understand why I can't deny deletion. I'm not sure why checking that permission has no effect, for example.

As an Administrator you can modify the ACL of any folder on your system which means you can add or deny the permission required to delete any folder or file at any time.

Although I am seemingly manipulating these settings, as I said, they have no effect. I am still able to delete files even when I deny the permission.
